# Robotium Sdk v17 doesn't appear test result on Emulator or Junit

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium

My Sdk is v17 and I don't have any error with this code. **But nothing show on emulator or Junit**.

Just showing this on console :

Does that mean my code is testing successfully?

```
[2012-05-20 17:26:08 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Installing MobilEpostaUyg-Test.apk...
[2012-05-20 17:26:15 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Success!
[2012-05-20 17:26:15 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Project dependency found, installing: MobilEpostaUyg
[2012-05-20 17:26:17 - MobilEpostaUyg] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-05-20 17:26:17 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
[2012-05-20 17:26:18 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Collecting test information
[2012-05-20 17:26:21 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2012-05-20 17:26:21 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Running tests...
[2012-05-20 17:26:23 - MobilEpostaUyg-Test] Test run finished
```

Test Code:

```
package com.mobil.eposta.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.mobil.eposta.MobilEpostaUygActivity;

public class LoginButtonTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MobilEpostaUygActivity> {

    private Solo solo;


    public LoginButtonTest() {
        super("com.mobil.eposta" ,MobilEpostaUygActivity.class );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation() ,  getActivity());
    }

    public void loginTest()
    {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("First Activity", MobilEpostaUygActivity.class );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to uninstall your app and the test app from the device and start over with fresh installations? Maybe that helps.

Comment: I fix the code with a video on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_8euppCz3k and thats help so much. But I have another problem now, I will edit it on my question after I edit it, Could you look at please..

Comment: I assume you are using Eclipse. Did you run the test as Android JUnit Test? The test results should show up in the JUnit view. If everything worked, you should get a green bar.

Comment: I improve the code which I asked here, and I got result on Junit and Emulator, thank you by the way